# Convert function with only AND Boolean operations

Tags: boolean, logic, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I have some function like

```
(A and ( B or c)) or (D and E and (F or H or R or P )))
```

and I want to convert that function to function with only and operations (of course if possible)
I find that with [DeMorgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) can be done some kind of transformations but I didn't manage to conver this function any ideas ?

I know that function

```
!(A or B) is equal to function !A and !B
```

but I could not find the equal function to the one above

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The function you mentioned:

```
!(A or B) = !A and !B
```

is the same as:

```
A or B = !(!A and !B)
```

So let's start by splitting your problem into two parts of ABC and DEFHRP.

```
(A and (B or C)) = (A and !(!B and !C))
(D and E and (F or H or R or P)) = (D and E and !(!F and !H and !R and !P))
```

Since these two parts are joined by an 'or', we can apply the equivalence again to get:

```
!(!(A and !(!B and !C)) and !(D and E and !(!F and !H and !R and !P)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a and (b or c)
```

is the same as

```
a and not (not b and not c)
```

You can test it [here](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aa%20%3D%20true%0Ab%20%3D%20false%0Ac%20%3D%20false%0A%0Ad%20%3D%20a%20and%20%28b%20or%20c%29%0A%0Aalert%20d%0A%0Ae%20%3D%20a%20and%20not%20%28not%20b%20and%20not%20c%29%0A%0Aalert%20e)

---

And for the more complex one:

```
d and e and (f or h or r)
```

is the same as

```
d and e and not(not f and not h and not r)
```

which is tested [here](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aa%20%3D%20true%0Ab%20%3D%20true%0Ac%20%3D%20true%0A%0Ad%20%3D%20a%20and%20%28b%20or%20c%29%0Ae%20%3D%20a%20and%20not%20%28not%20b%20and%20not%20c%29%0A%0Af%20%3D%20false%0Ah%20%3D%20false%0Ar%20%3D%20false%0A%0Ax%20%3D%20d%20and%20e%20and%20%28f%20or%20h%20or%20r%29%0Az%20%3D%20d%20and%20e%20and%20not%28not%20f%20and%20not%20h%20and%20not%20r%29%0A%0Aalert%20x%0Aalert%20z)

Answer (score 0):

The key substitution you're looking for is `A OR B => !(!A AND !B)`. Using this you can expand the expression.